# When $xyz=1$ why is $x+y+z\geq3$? ($x,y,z>0$)

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, ordered-fields

How can I prove the statement below without using the Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means?

$\forall x,y,z \in F  $ (F is an ordered field) $(x,y,z>0)$ $xyz=1 \implies x+y+z\geqslant3$

For the case where $x,y,z = 1$ it's easy to understand, but I fail to grasp how many more cases of $x,y,z$ ,I have to prove that $x+y+z\geqslant3$ work's for.

Comment: Well, if you don't want to use the AM-GM inequality directly, any _proof_ of the AM-GM inequality ought to work. Since what you want to show is basically AM-GM for three variables, that should be exactly what you're after.

Comment: @Arthur I see, so everything goes to the AM-GM proof I just need a specific case from that I guess...

Comment: Would you know Lagrange multipliers by any chance?

Comment: @Arnaud Mortier Lagrange multipliers works only for Real numbers isn't it?

Comment: Oh I see, in an abstract field. Well, right, it doesn't apply there.

Comment: @Arthur Not every proof will work here. We don't necessarily have roots in a generic ordered field. Nor exponentials and logarithms (some sleek proofs of AM-GM rely on those).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Or derivatives, which was used in one of the deleted answers, as well as the above comment. I know that. You would need to interpret my statement "any proof" in light of the context of a general ordered field, rather than the real numbers. It's a bit vague, you're right, but at this point there is nothing I can do about it other than deleting my original comment, and I don't think I will do that.

Comment: No harm done, @Arthur. Sorry about the fuss. Sometimes the desire to be pedantic gets the better of me.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen On the other hand, an ordered field has a real closure where square roots of positive elements exist. So one can use AM-GM.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen And some times I'm not pedantic enough. I like "moral mathematics" (for lack of a better term; "moral" as in "the moral of the story is...", not as in ethics and philosophy) and use it at any convenience. Some times it becomes too much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x\geq1$ and $y\leq1$.

Thus, $$(x-1)(y-1)\leq0$$ or
$$x+y\geq xy+1.$$
Thus, $$x+y+z\geq xy+1+z$$ and it's enough to prove
$$xy+z\geq2$$ or
$$xyz+1-xy-z\leq0$$ or
$$(xy-1)(z-1)\leq0,$$ which is obvious.

Comment: A good one! I recall using induction on the number of variables when given the task of proving AM-GM in high school (part of our IMO training). But it didn't go as smoothly as this :-)

Comment: good job תודה רבה:)

Comment: !הצליח You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Cauchy/reverse/forward-backward induction works in any ordered field:

Start with $$2^2ab \leq (a+b)^2$$ and deduce: (*forward induction*) $$4^4xyzu \leq (x+y+z+u)^4$$ by letting $a = x+y$, $b = z+u$.

Then let $u = \frac{x+y+z}3$ to get: (*backward induction*) 
$$\frac{4^4}3xyz(x+y+z) \leq \left(\frac43\right)^4(x+y+z)^4$$
Finally $x,y,z>0$ so $x+y+z>0$ and we can divide by it:
$$3^3xyz \leq (x+y+z)^3$$

To finish, note that we can't take cube roots(*), so proceed by contradiction: if $x+y+z<3$, the above gives a contradiction.

---

(*) Under the additional assumption that $x,y,z$ are cubes, say $a^3,b^3,c^3$, we can simply use the identity
$$x+y+z-3 = \frac12(a+b+c)\left((a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2\right)\geq0$$

Comment: Why there is $a$ for which $x=a^3$?

Comment: There aren't, below the line I give a second proof under this additional assumption.

Comment: If so, why you wrote  it?

Answer (score 0):

Given $u=x+y+z$, use Lagrange multipliers:
$$L=x+y+z+k(1-xyz)$$
$$\begin{cases} L_x=1-kyz=0 \\ L_y=1-kxz=0 \\ L_z=1-kxy=0 \\ L_k=1-xyz=0 \end{cases} \Rightarrow x=y=z=k=1.$$
Bordered Hessian:
$$\begin{vmatrix} 0 & yz & xz & xy \\ 
yz & 0 & -kz & -ky \\ 
xz & -kz & 0 & -kx \\
xy & -ky & -kx & 0\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} 0&1&1&1\\
1&0&-1&-1\\
1&-1&0&-1\\
1&-1&-1&0\end{vmatrix}.$$
$$\bar{H}_1=-1<0; \bar{H}_2=-2<0; \bar{H}_3=-3<0 \Rightarrow u(1,1,1)=3 \ (\text{min}).$$